# Getting an arbitrary point of the circle in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wrote a code using `tkz-euclide` to randomly pick a point on a circle and work from there as you can see in my question [How to control label positions in tikz-euclide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71072/how-to-control-label-positions-in-tikz-euclide). I have seen several questions already about randomizing the choosing of points in `TikZ` such as [Tangents to a circle from a point outside of it (tikz)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28678/tangents-to-a-circle-from-a-point-outside-of-it-tikz) and [Extract x, y coordinate of an arbitrary point in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz). And I could see that it is not that easy to do this. But how do we do it with just `TikZ`?

**Edit** I am sorry if my question is not that clear. What I am looking for is a solution that is written with the usual `TikZ` commands (in combination maybe with some TeX/LaTeX macros) that randomly chooses a point on the circle just like what `\tkzGetRandPointOn` does.

Comment: Could you explain for non-tkz users what `\tkzGetRandPointOn` does?  Looking at Peter Grill's code, I would do something like `\pgfmathsetmacro\ang{360*rnd}` to get a random angle and then generate the coordinate from that using sin and cosine.  Would that be enough, or do you need more?

Comment: @GarbageCollector What random finite set?

Comment: @AndrewStacey: The `\tkzGetRandPointOn` gets an arbitrary point of the target object. The code of Peter Grill was taken from my question in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71072/how-to-control-label-positions-in-tikz-euclide where I commented on each line to explain the code (from what I understand from the manual anyway).

Comment: @hpesoj626 So to do `\tkzGetRandPointOn` for a circle, all you need to do is generate a random angle which `\pgfmathsetmacro\ang{360*rnd}` does.  After that, it's just trigonometry.

Comment: @GarbageCollector But only one of them is randomly chosen.  The others are fixed.  If you want to ensure that the random point is not near to the fixed points (so that the labels don't overlap) then that's easy enough: define an exclusion zone.

Comment: @AndrewStacey, yes something like that. I will come back tomorrow.

Comment: @GarbageCollector, What I want is to choose only one arbitrary point of the circle and define any other point of the circle or object based on that first point.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4795/discussion-between-hpesoj626-and-andrew-stacey)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a very simple answer.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (center) at (1,2);
  \def\radius{2.5cm}
  % a circle
  \draw (center) circle[radius=\radius];

  % a random point of the circle
  \fill[red] (center) ++(rand*180:\radius) circle[radius=2pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The same idea in more detail:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % choose a seed for pseudo-random generator
  \pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate 10000000}

  % define a circle (center=O and \radius)
  \coordinate (O) at (1,2);
  \def\radius{2.5cm}

  % draw this circle and its center
  \draw (O) circle[radius=\radius];
  \fill (O) circle[radius=2pt] node[below left] {O};

  % define a random point (A) on this circle
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\angleA}{rand*180}
  \path (O) ++(\angleA:\radius) coordinate (A);

  % draw (A) with a label
  \fill[red] (A) circle[radius=2pt] ++(\angleA:1em) node {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To generate a pseudo-random number between -180 and 180, you can use one of the following expressions:

- `rand*180` (my solution)
- `rdn*360-180` (derived from Andrew Stacey's comment)
- `random(-180,180)` (an integer value only!)

The default seed of pseudo-random generator is `\time` × `\year`. Thus, it changes each minute. To choose a seed changing more frequently, use something like:

```
\pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate 10000000}
```

Comment: `\times` x `\year`: So that is why the positions of the points do not change sometimes even after several compiles. :)

Comment: @hpesoj626 With `pdftex`, you can use `\pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate 1000000}` to choose a more random seed.

Comment: That was nice of you to explain further. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Note that it is not TikZ solution and there is no guarantee that there is no duplicated points.

### Case 1 (three fixed, one randomed)

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\pstVerb
{
    /randval {rand 36000 mod 100 div} def % random number from 0.00 to 359.99
}

\begin{document}
\psLoop{30}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \pnode(0,0){O}
    \pstGeonode[CurveType=polygon,linejoin=2]
    (2,0){A}
    (2;30){B}
    (2;70){C}
    (!2 randval PtoC){D}
    \pstCircleOA{O}{A}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

### Case 2 (all randomed)

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\pstVerb
{
    /randval {rand 36000 mod 100 div} def % random number from 0.00 to 359.99
}

\begin{document}
\psLoop{30}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \pnode(0,0){O}
    \pstGeonode[CurveType=polygon,linejoin=2]
    (!2 randval PtoC){A}
    (!2 randval PtoC){B}
    (!2 randval PtoC){C}
    (!2 randval PtoC){D}
    \pstCircleOA{O}{A}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `(!2 rand 360 mod PtoC){D} ` do not need any additional definitions with `\pstVerb`

Comment: It looks simple enough in `pstricks`. I know that it is very powerful. I learned it first before I learned `tikz` but I can't say I understand it anymore. Looking back, I say that my reliance on `tikz` maybe mainly due to my heavy use of `pdflatex`. I have to revisit the manual. Thanks.