# Plotting line from angle command in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to use the following code to get a line between the perimeters of the circles, the `--(b)++(135:16pt)` is the bit that I'm having the problem with, it seems that it draws it to `(b)` and neglects the `++` part after, is there any way to bracket this so it draws it to `((b)++(135:16pt))`. Also, the same goes with the definition of coordinate `(c)`, it thinks it's the same as `(b)` not `(b)++whatever`.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin {tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\coordinate (a) at (0pt,0);
\coordinate (b) at (130pt,0);
\coordinate(c) at (b)++(0,10pt);
\draw (a) circle (28pt) (a) circle (22pt) (a)circle(20pt);
\draw (b) circle (16pt) (b) circle (12pt) (b)circle(10pt);
\draw(a)++(55:28pt)--(b)++(135:16pt);
\end {tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That syntax is not good for TikZ since it needs to understand a coordinate and some magic should happen inside the `(` and `)` characters. You can use `\draw([shift={(55:28pt)}]a)--([shift={(135:16pt)}]b) ;`. However, I would suggest to switch to `calc` library notation with `$` use. Check the manual for further details.

Comment: Will doing it with the calc library have any effect on the line quality? I'm noticing that as it's drawn now it's quite jagged. Perhaps it's just the angle though.

Comment: There shouldn't be an  interference on the line quality since it only affects the coordinate location. Try `\draw($(a)+(55:28pt)$) -- ($(b)+(135:16pt)$);` by adding `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`.

Comment: Thanks percusse, I had no idea that using the calc notation was that easy.

Comment: By the way if you want to create tangents, have a look at [How can I draw a tangent ending smoothly in a circle?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41794/3235)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several techniques to do this. One of them is suggested by percusse.

The following shows the first two techniques in one example. Later I show a better example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin {tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\coordinate (a) at (0pt,0);
\coordinate (b) at (130pt,0);
\coordinate(c) at (b)++(0,10pt);
\draw (a) circle (28pt) (a) circle (22pt) (a)circle(20pt);
\draw (b) circle (16pt) (b) circle (12pt) (b)circle(10pt);
% First techique:
\draw (a)+(55:28pt)  coordinate (a@55)
      (b)+(135:16pt) coordinate (b@135)
      (a@55) -- (b@135);
% Second technique (requires calc.)
\draw ($(a)+(55:28pt)$) -- ($(b)+(-15:16pt)$);
\end {tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This example is based on your code but it's not very maintainable. For example, what if the radius of one circle changes: you'd have to make several changes. The following shows how you may overcome this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin {tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw let \n{first  outer}={28pt},
          \n{first  middle}={20pt},
          \n{first  inner}={10pt},
          \n{second outer}={16pt},
          \n{second middle}={12pt},
          \n{second inner}={10pt},
          \n{first angle}={55},
          \n{second angle}={135}
      in
      (0,0)     coordinate (first centre)
      (130pt,0) coordinate (second centre)
      \foreach \radius in {outer,middle,inner} {
          (first centre)  circle (\n{first \radius})
          (second centre) circle (\n{second \radius})
      }
      ($(first centre) +(\n{first angle}:\n{first outer})$) --
      ($(second centre) +(\n{second angle}:\n{second outer})$);
\end {tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! Do you mind adding my first comment and finally using the node syntax `\draw (a.55) -- (b.135)`  as additional solutions such that it becomes more comprehensive?

Comment: I meant after making `a,b` circle nodes.

Comment: Thank you Marc for such a detailed reply! I'd been wondering how I could make my code more adaptable to changes- your second set of code shows me perfectly, i'll study this and try and implement it in the next diagram I draw.

Is the easiest way to construct a 'fillet' or blend between that line and the circle to reduce the line length and then use a short bezier curve to connect- using a control point with trial and error until it looks 'right'?

Comment: @percusse Is this what you meant?

Comment: @Andy Glad it helped. I am not sure what you mean exactly. Perhaps if you can show an example, we can have a look.