# Drawing a convex hull of disks

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw the convex hull of a set of disks, as shown below from [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/092577219290015K) article.

[image]

All I could do was to compute the points by hand (approximately):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]

            \draw (-4,2) circle (2cm);
            \draw (2,0)  circle (7cm);      
            \draw (0,6)  circle (4cm);
            \draw (8,2)  circle (2cm);
            \draw (8,-6)  circle (8cm);
            \draw (4,-4)  circle (6.1cm);
            \node (G) at (-5.8, 2.8) {};
            \node (H) at (-3.6, 7.6) {};
            \node (I) at (2.7, 8.9) {};
            \node (J) at (6.8, 5.1) {};
            \node (K) at (9.1, 3.7) {};
            \node (L) at (13.3, 0) {};
            \node (M) at (1.8, -11.1) {};
            \node (N) at (-0.7, -8) {};
            \node (P) at (-0.9, -7.7) {};
            \node (O) at (-3.6, -4.2) {};
            \node (R) at (-4.6, -2.3) {};
            \node (Q) at (-5.9, 1.3) {};

            \draw[thick, red] (G)--(H) ;
            \draw[thick, red] (I)--(K) ;
            \draw[thick, red] (K)--(L) ;
            \draw[thick, red] (M)--(N) ;
            \draw[thick, red] (P)--(O) ;
            \draw[thick, red] (R)--(Q) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But it looks ridiculous:

[image]

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41794/how-can-i-draw-a-tangent-ending-smoothly-in-a-circle

Comment: @percusse This is exactly what I want, but using `\node` to draw circles makes things a lot harder for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a style, which makes it nearly as easy to draw circles with nodes as with `\draw`. Then the `tangent cs` can be used as shown in percusses [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41795/110842).

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
    \tikzset{onlycircle/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=2*#1,transform shape}}
        \node[onlycircle=2cm]   (A) at (-4, 2) {};
        \node[onlycircle=7cm]   (B) at ( 2, 0) {};
        \node[onlycircle=4cm]   (C) at ( 0, 6) {};
        \node[onlycircle=2cm]   (D) at ( 8, 2) {};
        \node[onlycircle=8cm]   (E) at ( 8,-6) {};
        \node[onlycircle=6.1cm] (F) at ( 4,-4) {};

        \draw[red] (tangent cs:node=A,point={(C.north west)}) -- (tangent cs:node=C,point={(A.north west)},solution=2);
        \draw[red] (tangent cs:node=C,point={(D.north east)}) -- (tangent cs:node=D,point={(C.north east)},solution=2);
        \draw[red] (tangent cs:node=D,point={(E.north east)}) -- (tangent cs:node=E,point={(D.north east)},solution=2);
        \draw[red] (tangent cs:node=E,point={(F.south west)}) -- (tangent cs:node=F,point={(E.south west)},solution=2);
        \draw[red] (tangent cs:node=F,point={(B.south west)}) -- (tangent cs:node=B,point={(F.south west)},solution=2);
        \draw[red] (tangent cs:node=B,point={(A.south west)}) -- (tangent cs:node=A,point={(B.south west)},solution=2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So, is not possible to determine the tangent in automatic way?

Comment: @Sigur marmots answer is easier to use. But getting all the necessary tangents automatically requires quite some math. And honestly, I don't want to spend the time to figure this out. May be someone more familiar with this stuff is willing to. Or go ahead and knock yourself out ;-) I would upvote it...

Comment: I even don't know how to solve it mathematically... lol Given `n` circles (I mean, `n` pairs `(C_i,r_i)` for centers and radius), how to find the convex hull? I never try to solve it.

Comment: Actually, the algorithm is given the paper that I refer to in the question :)

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness. Since there were two answers in @percusse's link, I was curious how they compare. The bottom-line is that [@percusse's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41795/121799) is an almost perfect approximation. [Paul Gaborit's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76226/121799) seems to be the exact one. In what follows, I add a macro to @Mike's answer that uses Paul Gaborit's answer.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
% #1: options, #2: circle node 1, #3: circle node 2
\newcommand{\DrawGaboritTangent}[4][]{
  \path let \p1=($(#2.center)-(#2.west)$), \p2=($(#3.center)-(#3.west)$) in
  \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\radiusA}{\x1/veclen(\x1,\x2)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\radiusB}{\x2/veclen(\x1,\x2)}}
  \ifdim\radiusA pt>\radiusB pt
  coordinate (GaboritC) at (barycentric cs:#2=-\radiusB,#3=\radiusA)
  \else
  coordinate (GaboritC) at (barycentric cs:#2=\radiusB,#3=-\radiusA);
  \fi
  ;
  \draw[#1] (tangent cs:node=#2,point={(GaboritC)},solution=#4) -- 
  (tangent cs:node=#3,point={(GaboritC)},solution=#4);
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
    \tikzset{onlycircle/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=2*#1,transform shape}}
        \node[onlycircle=2cm]   (A) at (-4, 2) {};
        \node[onlycircle=7cm]   (B) at ( 2, 0) {};
        \node[onlycircle=4cm]   (C) at ( 0, 6) {};
        \node[onlycircle=2cm]   (D) at ( 8, 2) {};
        \node[onlycircle=8cm]   (E) at ( 8,-6) {};
        \node[onlycircle=6.1cm] (F) at ( 4,-4) {};
        \draw[red] (tangent cs:node=A,point={(C.north west)}) -- (tangent cs:node=C,point={(A.north west)},solution=2);
        \DrawGaboritTangent[blue,opacity=0.5]{A}{C}{2}
        \draw[red,opacity=0.5] (tangent cs:node=C,point={(D.north east)}) -- (tangent cs:node=D,point={(C.north east)},solution=2);
        \DrawGaboritTangent[blue,opacity=0.5]{C}{D}{1}
        \draw[red,opacity=0.5] (tangent cs:node=D,point={(E.north east)}) -- (tangent cs:node=E,point={(D.north east)},solution=2);
        \DrawGaboritTangent[blue,opacity=0.5]{D}{E}{2}
        \draw[red,opacity=0.5] (tangent cs:node=E,point={(F.south west)}) -- (tangent cs:node=F,point={(E.south west)},solution=2);
        \DrawGaboritTangent[blue,opacity=0.5]{E}{F}{1}
        \draw[red,opacity=0.5] (tangent cs:node=F,point={(B.south west)}) -- (tangent cs:node=B,point={(F.south west)},solution=2);
        \DrawGaboritTangent[blue,opacity=0.5]{F}{B}{2}
        \draw[red,opacity=0.5] (tangent cs:node=B,point={(A.south west)}) -- (tangent cs:node=A,point={(B.south west)},solution=2);
        \DrawGaboritTangent[blue,opacity=0.5]{A}{B}{1}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The different tangents are hard to distinguish by eye.

Comment: +1: easier to use. I guess the differences between the tangents are mainly because of rounding errors.

Comment: @Mike Thanks! I am not sure if these are rounding errors, see [Paul Gaborit's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76226/121799), where the differences are computed. But in the case at hand, these do not matter, yet in Paul Gaborit's example, in which there is a large hierarchy between the radii, one can see some difference.

Comment: You're right, it is more accurate.