# Connect spy with tangent lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, spy

I am using TikZ `spy` library to magnify part of my plot, and I would like to connect the spy point and the magnifying glass with two tangents to both circles (see second example). I found and implemented an algorithm to compute such lines (or, better, the four interesting points in the two circles), but I cannot understand how to pass to it the coordinates and radii of `spy`'s circles. It seems to me that there is a mismatch between numbers, point and centimeters.

Is there a way to get what I described?

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    spy using outlines = {circle,size=3cm,magnification=5,connect spies},
]
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[domain = 0:2*pi] expression {sin(deg(x))};
\coordinate (spy point) at (axis cs: 0, 0);
\coordinate (magnifying glass) at (rel axis cs: -0.4, 0.2);
\end{axis}

\spy on (spy point) in node at (magnifying glass);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\radiusa{0.3}
\def\radiusb{3}

\def\xa{5}
\def\ya{3}

\def\xb{0}
\def\yb{0}

\coordinate (magnifying glass) at (\xa, \ya);
\coordinate (spy point) at (\xb, \yb);

\pgfmathsetmacro\xp{(\xb * \radiusa - \xa * \radiusb) / (\radiusa - \radiusb)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\yp{(\yb * \radiusa - \ya * \radiusb) / (\radiusa - \radiusb)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\distancea{sqrt((\xp - \xa) * (\xp - \xa) + (\yp - \ya) * (\yp - \ya) - \radiusa * \radiusa))}
\pgfmathsetmacro\distanceb{sqrt((\xp - \xb) * (\xp - \xb) + (\yp - \yb) * (\yp - \yb) - \radiusb * \radiusb))}
\pgfmathsetmacro\denoma{(\xp - \xa)*(\xp - \xa) + (\yp - \ya)*(\yp - \ya)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\denomb{(\xp - \xb)*(\xp - \xb) + (\yp - \yb)*(\yp - \yb)}

\pgfmathsetmacro\xc{(\radiusa * \radiusa * (\xp - \xa) + \radiusa * (\yp - \ya) * \distancea) / \denoma + \xa}
\pgfmathsetmacro\yc{(\radiusa * \radiusa * (\yp - \ya) - \radiusa * (\xp - \xa) * \distancea) / \denoma + \ya}

\pgfmathsetmacro\xe{(\radiusa * \radiusa * (\xp - \xa) - \radiusa * (\yp - \ya) * \distancea) / \denoma + \xa}
\pgfmathsetmacro\ye{(\radiusa * \radiusa * (\yp - \ya) + \radiusa * (\xp - \xa) * \distancea) / \denoma + \ya}

\pgfmathsetmacro\xd{(\radiusb * \radiusb * (\xp - \xb) + \radiusb * (\yp - \yb) * \distanceb) / \denomb + \xb}
\pgfmathsetmacro\yd{(\radiusb * \radiusb * (\yp - \yb) - \radiusb * (\xp - \xb) * \distanceb) / \denomb + \yb}

\pgfmathsetmacro\xf{(\radiusb * \radiusb * (\xp - \xb) - \radiusb * (\yp - \yb) * \distanceb) / \denomb + \xb}
\pgfmathsetmacro\yf{(\radiusb * \radiusb * (\yp - \yb) + \radiusb * (\xp - \xb) * \distanceb) / \denomb + \yb}


\draw (magnifying glass) circle(\radiusa);
\draw (spy point) circle(\radiusb);

% \draw (\xa, \ya) node[scale=3, green] {.};
% \draw (\xb, \yb) node[scale=3, green] {.};
% \draw (\xp, \yp) node[scale=3, blue] {.};
% \draw (\xc, \yc) node[scale=3, red] {.};
% \draw (\xd, \yd) node[scale=3, red] {.};
% \draw (\xe, \ye) node[scale=3, red] {.};
% \draw (\xf, \yf) node[scale=3, red] {.};

% \draw (\xa, \ya) -- (\xp, \yp);
% \draw (\xb, \yb) -- (\xp, \yp);

\draw (\xc, \yc) -- (\xd, \yd);
\draw (\xe, \ye) -- (\xf, \yf);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a proposal without external programs. I am using your methods to compute the tangents but would like to remark that this has also been done in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7209/121799). The coordinates of the relevant nodes are extracted with `calc`, and the conversion to cm is as simple as a multiplication by `1pt/1cm`.

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    spy using outlines = {circle,size=3cm,magnification=5,connect spies},
    get coords/.code={\xdef\xa{\n1}\xdef\ya{\n2}
    \xdef\xb{\n3}\xdef\yb{\n4}}
]
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[domain = 0:2*pi] expression {sin(deg(x))};
\coordinate (spy point) at (axis cs: 0, 0);
\coordinate (magnifying glass) at (rel axis cs: -0.4, 0.2);
\end{axis}

\spy[spy connection path={
\def\radiusa{0.3}
\def\radiusb{1.5}
\path let \p1=(tikzspyonnode),\p2=(tikzspyinnode),
\n1={\x1*1pt/1cm},\n2={\y1*1pt/1cm},\n3={\x2*1pt/1cm},\n4={\y2*1pt/1cm} in [get coords];
\pgfmathsetmacro\xp{(\xb * \radiusa - \xa * \radiusb) / (\radiusa - \radiusb)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\yp{(\yb * \radiusa - \ya * \radiusb) / (\radiusa - \radiusb)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\distancea{sqrt((\xp - \xa) * (\xp - \xa) + (\yp - \ya) * (\yp - \ya) - \radiusa * \radiusa))}
\pgfmathsetmacro\distanceb{sqrt((\xp - \xb) * (\xp - \xb) + (\yp - \yb) * (\yp - \yb) - \radiusb * \radiusb))}
\pgfmathsetmacro\denoma{(\xp - \xa)*(\xp - \xa) + (\yp - \ya)*(\yp - \ya)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\denomb{(\xp - \xb)*(\xp - \xb) + (\yp - \yb)*(\yp - \yb)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xc{(\radiusa * \radiusa * (\xp - \xa) + \radiusa * (\yp - \ya) * \distancea) / \denoma + \xa}
\pgfmathsetmacro\yc{(\radiusa * \radiusa * (\yp - \ya) - \radiusa * (\xp - \xa) * \distancea) / \denoma + \ya}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xe{(\radiusa * \radiusa * (\xp - \xa) - \radiusa * (\yp - \ya) * \distancea) / \denoma + \xa}
\pgfmathsetmacro\ye{(\radiusa * \radiusa * (\yp - \ya) + \radiusa * (\xp - \xa) * \distancea) / \denoma + \ya}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xd{(\radiusb * \radiusb * (\xp - \xb) + \radiusb * (\yp - \yb) * \distanceb) / \denomb + \xb}
\pgfmathsetmacro\yd{(\radiusb * \radiusb * (\yp - \yb) - \radiusb * (\xp - \xb) * \distanceb) / \denomb + \yb}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xf{(\radiusb * \radiusb * (\xp - \xb) - \radiusb * (\yp - \yb) * \distanceb) / \denomb + \xb}
\pgfmathsetmacro\yf{(\radiusb * \radiusb * (\yp - \yb) + \radiusb * (\xp - \xb) * \distanceb) / \denomb + \yb}
\draw (\xc, \yc) -- (\xd, \yd);
\draw (\xe, \ye) -- (\xf, \yf);}] 
on (spy point) in node at (magnifying glass);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: A way to save this as a style. Clearly, one can improve on this e.g. by not hard-coding the radii.

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    spy using outlines = {circle,size=3cm,magnification=5,connect spies},
    get coords/.code={\xdef\xa{\n1}\xdef\ya{\n2}
    \xdef\xb{\n3}\xdef\yb{\n4}},
    my connector/.store in=\myconnector,
    my connector={
\def\radiusa{0.3}
\def\radiusb{1.5}
\path let \p1=(tikzspyonnode),\p2=(tikzspyinnode),
\n1={\x1*1pt/1cm},\n2={\y1*1pt/1cm},\n3={\x2*1pt/1cm},\n4={\y2*1pt/1cm} in [get coords];
\pgfmathsetmacro\xp{(\xb * \radiusa - \xa * \radiusb) / (\radiusa - \radiusb)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\yp{(\yb * \radiusa - \ya * \radiusb) / (\radiusa - \radiusb)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\distancea{sqrt((\xp - \xa) * (\xp - \xa) + (\yp - \ya) * (\yp - \ya) - \radiusa * \radiusa))}
\pgfmathsetmacro\distanceb{sqrt((\xp - \xb) * (\xp - \xb) + (\yp - \yb) * (\yp - \yb) - \radiusb * \radiusb))}
\pgfmathsetmacro\denoma{(\xp - \xa)*(\xp - \xa) + (\yp - \ya)*(\yp - \ya)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\denomb{(\xp - \xb)*(\xp - \xb) + (\yp - \yb)*(\yp - \yb)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xc{(\radiusa * \radiusa * (\xp - \xa) + \radiusa * (\yp - \ya) * \distancea) / \denoma + \xa}
\pgfmathsetmacro\yc{(\radiusa * \radiusa * (\yp - \ya) - \radiusa * (\xp - \xa) * \distancea) / \denoma + \ya}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xe{(\radiusa * \radiusa * (\xp - \xa) - \radiusa * (\yp - \ya) * \distancea) / \denoma + \xa}
\pgfmathsetmacro\ye{(\radiusa * \radiusa * (\yp - \ya) + \radiusa * (\xp - \xa) * \distancea) / \denoma + \ya}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xd{(\radiusb * \radiusb * (\xp - \xb) + \radiusb * (\yp - \yb) * \distanceb) / \denomb + \xb}
\pgfmathsetmacro\yd{(\radiusb * \radiusb * (\yp - \yb) - \radiusb * (\xp - \xb) * \distanceb) / \denomb + \yb}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xf{(\radiusb * \radiusb * (\xp - \xb) - \radiusb * (\yp - \yb) * \distanceb) / \denomb + \xb}
\pgfmathsetmacro\yf{(\radiusb * \radiusb * (\yp - \yb) + \radiusb * (\xp - \xb) * \distanceb) / \denomb + \yb}
\draw (\xc, \yc) -- (\xd, \yd);
\draw (\xe, \ye) -- (\xf, \yf);}
]
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[domain = 0:2*pi] expression {sin(deg(x))};
\coordinate (spy point) at (axis cs: 0, 0);
\coordinate (magnifying glass) at (rel axis cs: -0.4, 0.2);
\end{axis}

\spy[spy connection path=\myconnector] 
on (spy point) in node at (magnifying glass);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is almost perfect! And it is not necessary to wrap the plot with a `scope`, as it was with my method. Is there a way to refactor that big `spy connection path={...}` as a reusable style with `\tikzset{...}`? I tried it but it reverted back to the default single line connection.

Comment: @Claudio I added a way to make this a style. (I have no time for polishing this right now. However, it works.)

Comment: Couldn’t this also be added to the 'spy'-library to be easily available as an option? I can see many people wanting this.

Comment: @gr4nt3d Could this be added? Well, this would require 3 steps: 1. clean this up (I plan to do that later this week); 2. test this in many constellations (could be done if many users use a polished version in their code and report bugs/problems). 3. Send a feature request to the authors (I guess that the chances that this will be implemented are slim).

Answer (score 3):

I ended up implementing the algorithm in a short Python script and manually extracting the points' coordinated from TikZ source.

Note that I used an inner `scope` otherwise the tangent lines itself were visible inside the magnifying glass. There is also a visible difference in line width between the tangents and the spy circle, so the figure needs to be tuned a bit.

It is still less convenient than having everything implemented in TikZ.

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\xcoord[2][center]{{%
    \pgfpointanchor{#2}{#1}%
    \pgfmathparse{\pgf@x/\pgf@xx}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}}
\newcommand\ycoord[2][center]{{%
    \pgfpointanchor{#2}{#1}%
    \pgfmathparse{\pgf@y/\pgf@yy}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[
    spy using outlines = {circle,size=3cm,magnification=5},
]
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[domain = 0:2*pi] expression {sin(deg(x))};
\coordinate (spy point) at (axis cs: 0, 0);
\coordinate (magnifying glass) at (rel axis cs: -0.4, 0.2);
\coordinate (a) at (rel axis cs: 0.5, 1.1);
\end{axis}
\node at (a) {spy point: \xcoord{spy point}, \ycoord{spy point}, glass: \xcoord{magnifying glass}, \ycoord{magnifying glass}};

\spy on (spy point) in node at (magnifying glass);
\end{scope}
\coordinate (c) at (-1.6589690159337693, 0.10010961563788023);
\coordinate (d) at (0.7862061968132461, 2.6420219231275763);
\coordinate (e) at (-2.962541913303562, 2.6233998438799935);
\coordinate (f) at (0.5254916173392875, 3.1466799687759988);
\draw (c) -- (d);
\draw (e) -- (f);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
from math import sqrt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main():
    radiusa = 1.5
    radiusb = 1.5 / 5
    xa = -2.74
    ya = 1.14
    xb = 0.57
    yb = 2.85

    figure, ax = plt.subplots()
    circlea = plt.Circle((xa, ya), radiusa, color='C0')
    circleb = plt.Circle((xb, yb), radiusb, color='C0')
    ax.add_artist(circlea)
    ax.add_artist(circleb)

    (xc, yc), (xd, yd), (xe, ye), (xf, yf) = compute(xa, ya, radiusa, xb, yb, radiusb)

    ax.plot([xc, xd], [yc, yd], color='C0')
    ax.plot([xe, xf], [ye, yf], color='C0')

    ax.set_xlim(
        min(xa - radiusa, xb - radiusb),
        max(xa + radiusa, xb + radiusb),
    )
    ax.set_ylim(
        min(ya - radiusa, yb - radiusb),
        max(ya + radiusa, yb + radiusb),
    )

    print("\\coordinate (c) at ({}, {});".format(xc, yc))
    print("\\coordinate (d) at ({}, {});".format(xd, yd))
    print("\\coordinate (e) at ({}, {});".format(xe, ye))
    print("\\coordinate (f) at ({}, {});".format(xf, yf))

    plt.show()


def compute(xa, ya, radiusa, xb, yb, radiusb):
    xp = (xb * radiusa - xa * radiusb) / (radiusa - radiusb)
    yp = (yb * radiusa - ya * radiusb) / (radiusa - radiusb)
    distancea = sqrt((xp - xa) * (xp - xa) + (yp - ya) * (yp - ya) - radiusa * radiusa)
    distanceb = sqrt((xp - xb) * (xp - xb) + (yp - yb) * (yp - yb) - radiusb * radiusb)
    denoma = (xp - xa)*(xp - xa) + (yp - ya)*(yp - ya)
    denomb = (xp - xb)*(xp - xb) + (yp - yb)*(yp - yb)

    xc = (radiusa * radiusa * (xp - xa) + radiusa * (yp - ya) * distancea) / denoma + xa
    yc = (radiusa * radiusa * (yp - ya) - radiusa * (xp - xa) * distancea) / denoma + ya

    xe = (radiusa * radiusa * (xp - xa) - radiusa * (yp - ya) * distancea) / denoma + xa
    ye = (radiusa * radiusa * (yp - ya) + radiusa * (xp - xa) * distancea) / denoma + ya

    xd = (radiusb * radiusb * (xp - xb) + radiusb * (yp - yb) * distanceb) / denomb + xb
    yd = (radiusb * radiusb * (yp - yb) - radiusb * (xp - xb) * distanceb) / denomb + yb

    xf = (radiusb * radiusb * (xp - xb) - radiusb * (yp - yb) * distanceb) / denomb + xb
    yf = (radiusb * radiusb * (yp - yb) + radiusb * (xp - xb) * distanceb) / denomb + yb

    return (xc, yc), (xd, yd), (xe, ye), (xf, yf)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```