# MetaPost - Tangent line between two paths

Tags: metapost, tangent

I'm trying to make a function that given 2 paths would draw all the lines that are common tangents of them.

More specifically I was trying to draw the common tangent of 2 ellipses so that it would look like a projected view of a cone or a cylinder.
Something like this:

[image]

**What I've tried:** I followed another post here that given a point drew the tangent of a path, With that, I can manually pick a point on the second path that looks like the tangent, but how can I do it automatically and actually correct? I'm not very familiar with the `whatever` operator or the MetaFont `solve` macro but I think I could use them as an answer.

The body of the function would have something like this:

```
pair T,V,X,Y; path P,W;

P:=fullcircle scaled 100; W:=fullcircle scaled 200 shifted (400,100);
T:= point 2.5 of W; %Hand picked point on path W
V:= point 6 of W; %Hand picked point on path W

draw P withpen pencircle scaled 10;
draw W withpen pencircle scaled 10;

vardef f(expr t) = angle direction t of P - angle (T - point t of P) < eps enddef;

X = point solve f (11, 10) of P;
Y = point solve f (9, 14.5) of P;

draw X -- T withpen pencircle scaled 5 withcolor red;
draw Y -- V withpen pencircle scaled 5 withcolor red;
```

Which led to the result above.

**Edit:** To make myself more clear, I'm looking for the tangent of a **generic curve** and not only circles, example:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Welcome! Does [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162445/52406) help you?

Comment: Thank you! Hope I can help somebody to

Comment: @mickep it seems so! Thanks! Sorry for asking something that already had an answer for some reason I just couldn´t find it

Comment: Don't worry about that. Next time you might have better luck when searching for old questions. If that one really solved your problem, you can close this question as a duplicate of it. Again, welcome!

Comment: @mickep I read it more thoroughly and it seems like a step in the right direction, but not exactly the answer, the example only works for circles, it probably was my fault that it led to confusion since the image I used was of two circles. 
What I actually wanted was the tangent of  2 different generic **paths**, in my case specifically I'm using ellipses if it makes it easier.

Comment: Ok, good point. I am looking forward to see answers on this one.

Comment: Sections 9.11, 9.12, and 9.13 of [Drawing with Metapost](https://ctan.org/pkg/drawing-with-metapost?lang=en) deal with tangents from points to circles and from circles to circles.  Section 16.3.1 shows how to do tangents to ellipses...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think [tangents to arbitrary Bezier curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2149009/62654) is very easy geometrically.  But here is a toy example that might provide a starting point.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
  path a, b;
  a = origin .. (40, 20) .. (80, -30) .. (50, -60);
  b = (50, 90) .. (90, 50) .. (200, 20) .. (240, 50);

  for t = 0 step 1/64 until length a:
    numeric u; u = directiontime direction t of a of b;
    if u > 0:
      numeric aa;
      aa = abs(angle direction t of a - angle (point u of b - point t of a));
      if aa < 1:
        draw point t of a -- point u of b withcolor 3/4 red;
      fi
    fi
  endfor
  drawarrow a;
  drawarrow b;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Compile this with `lualatex` to get a PDF that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Perfect!!! I imagined that it would have to be done by brute force I'm just not familiar with MetaPost syntax! Btw thanks for the answer in the other post, it helped me ask this one properly!

Comment: One other thing, I'm very new here, do I have to close this question now that it has been answered? and how do I do this lol?

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE.  You might like to read [this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/15036).  Particularly the third bullet.